# AWS Codepipeline deploy step with no relevant changes fails to execute with "Update to resource type AWS::CodeDeploy::Application is not supported"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have a CDK based CodePipeline with a 'Deploy' Step for a Lambda function that started to fail recently, but succeeded already multiple times for this branch in the past. The odd thing about it, compared to the deploying fine  production branch:

- the code changes are minimal and passing ci the unit test and all other steps (2 loc)
- the only other change is a changed version number of the deployed application in npm's package.json file
- The CDK Stack did not see changes recently.
- The failing step is the one where the CI pipeline tries to deploy the lambda based application via cloudformation. When review the error in cloudformation, the Error 'Update to resource type AWS::CodeDeploy::Application is not supported' pops up for the ressource type 'AWS::CodeDeploy::Application which is deployed by a 'CodePipelineAction.S3DeployAction'.

The error seems to be regarding the created deploy stack and not a resource in it.

Update: I got a answer from AWS Support

> This is a known issue which you can track on the GitHub CDK issues. I encourage you to add your voice and experience to this issue. The more input we have, the more visibility we have to improve the service. Please see the link below:

```
 https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/15947
```

If you are updating this resource's tags, there is a CDK workaround. You can add the Exclude Resources Types within your construct. Below is a sample of how this would look:

```
const tagOptions = {
  excludeResourceTypes: ['AWS::CodeDeploy::Application'],
};
cdk.Tags.of(deployment).add('Name', `buffer-${props.environment}`, tagOptions);
```

The reason why it broke may be: It seems that this resource type didn't support tags before, and now it does, leading to the issue.

Comment: You will need to add a lot more detail. To start, at what step does it fail, what is the error message?

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I added it.

Comment: This is a bug. You'll need to destroy the stack and redeploy. https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/946

Comment: To confirm this, you can check the output of `cdk diff` to see if the tags indeed changed.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/319#issuecomment-569718498

Comment: @gshpychka 'You'll need to destroy the stack and redeploy' .. was not required. I added the tags and let my pipeline run. Your mileage might vary